# Usos de la palabra "papichulo"

Tags: uso-de-palabras, coloquialismos, significado

Debido a la inclusión de la palabra **papichulo** en el nuevo diccionario de la RAE, mi pregunta es muy sencilla: ¿Qué significados y usos tiene la palabra **papichulo**? Sé que el diccionario recoge el significado (aún no está en línea la última versión), pero quiero saber sus usos en cada país (que pueden ser diferentes).

Comment: Parece ser que la palabra procede del _reggaeton_ y designa a un hombre físicamente atractivo. No tenía ni idea de que la habían incluido en el diccionario.

Comment: Jamás la había oído, ignoro su significado (Argentina). Sí conozco "chulo" (aunque aquí no se usa), así que, de tener que adivinar el significado, apuntaría por ahí.

Comment: @Diego Me inclino más con que su procedencia sea de las regiones en países que lidan con el Mar Caribe.

Comment: @David, lo clavas porque el Urban Dictionary dice que "_Papi Chulo to Puerto Ricans and Dominicans means a guy who's tha Mac Daddy, tha PIMP Papa!_". Creo que es el único uso que tiene la palabra.

Comment: En Cuba se usa mucho con el significado que dice @Mauricio en su respuesta, tengo memoria de esa palabra desde que tengo uso de razon y tengo 30 años, se debe haber popularizado con el reggaetón fuera del caribe

Comment: Incluso a los niños pequeños se les dicen `papichulos` para decirles lindos, por ejemplo `que papichulo mas lindo`

Comment: Es un error grave de la RAE. No se pueden incorporar palabras nuevas que sean redundantes e inexpresivas, como en este caso, una palabra demasiado obvia y una *palabra compuesta* de "papi" (= "tío" en lenguaje callejero en España) y "chulo" (= "protector de prostitutas; vanidoso"). Es lo que yo llamo una palabra con mucha "entropía", mucho desorden, que aporta muy poco, que es demasiado larga, que suena mal al oído, que termina negativizando la dinámica expresiva de una lengua.

Answer (score 5):

La historia de la palabra *papichulo* se puede remontar a uno de los primeros temas del [reggaetón](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reguet%C3%B3n); el siguiente [tema musical](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kVsYckNXYqM) hace uso de la palabra *papichulo* (el cual adquirió una gran popularidad por aquellos tiempos).

Según la [fuente](http://www.eltiempo.com/entretenimiento/musica-y-libros/presentan-el-nuevo-diccionario-de-la-real-academia-espanola-rae/14694858), el significado de *papichulo* es:

> **Papichulo:** En el lenguaje coloquial de México, Paraguay y Puerto Rico, papichulo es un "hombre que, por su atractivo físico, es objeto de deseo".

Su uso en Colombia no es diferente al trasmitido por el reggaetón, aunque no es muy frecuente escuchar esta palabra (pero no por ello olvidado).

Adicionalmente, he escuchado otros términos para referirse a este tipo de hombres:

> - Galán.
> - Mono.
> - Guapo.
> - [Papacito](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?key=pap%E1).
> - [Churro <sub>amer. col. Persona guapa o atractiva.</sub>](http://www.wordreference.com/definicion/churro)

Comment: No crea que sea exclusivo de esas regiones. Habrá que esperar a alguien de Centroamérica o del Caribe.

Comment: En Cuba se usa mucho con el significado que tu dices, tengo memoria de esa palabra desde que tengo uso de razon y tengo 30 años, se debe haber popularizado con el reggaetón fuera del caribe

Comment: @David Personalmente, la definición presentada por la [fuente adjunta](http://www.eltiempo.com/entretenimiento/musica-y-libros/presentan-el-nuevo-diccionario-de-la-real-academia-espanola-rae/14694858) así como de otras fuentes disponibles en internet (y _ligadas_ a la definición **inicial** dada por la RAE) no me parecen completas, estoy de acuerdo en esperar la información compartida por otras zonas de América.

Answer (score 3):

### Papichulo:

Generalmente en el uso vulgar de la lengua:

- **Papi:**

> *Hace referencia a una persona, del sexo masculino, utilizado por las
>   mujeres para referirse de forma cariñosa a su pareja, novio, amante, o platónico (amor imposible).*

- **Chulo:**

> *Hace referencia a la moda, una persona chula, es quién se viste a la
>   moda, o tiene mucho estilo (Cool en ingles), que tiene facha, buena
>   pinta.*

En España es sinónimo de algo genial, que gusta mucho. una palabra similar es **Mola**.

---

### Por lo tanto, Papichulo:

Es la unión de esas dos palabras, papi, y chulo, dicho de una chica, al, chico que le gusta, amante, pareja, etc. Y a la vez tiene el plus, que al decirle papichulo le dice que es lindo, bien vestido, y que está *"en la onda"*.

Answer (score 2):

En México jamás he oído esa palabra como un todo. La **frase** la recuerdo el reggaetón de hace años. *Papi chulo* [Así con espacio] lo entiendo como *papi* de *tú hombre atractivo* y *chulo* significando hermoso pero de eso a que aparezca en el diccionario es una reverenda tontería. Hay palabras más relevantes, con más historia y que REALMENTE se usan que siguen en discusión sobre si deberían estar o no en los diccionarios.

Answer (score 1):

En Colombia he oido que se usa en jerga callejera en Bogota,  para denotar a un proxeneta, tambien conocido como chulo o en ingles pimp.

Answer (score 1):

Pues en la Rep.Dom. esta expresión tiene varios significados de acuerdo al contexto en donde se aplique:

- Papi-chulo: hombre que es muy atractivo ("mangote", "que está bueno").
- Papi-chulo: palabra cariñosa entre familiares y amigos muy cercanos  (la madre se la dice a su niño; la novia/esposa a su novio/marido, la mejor amiga al amigo...en Puerto Rico es común entre hombres decirse "papi/papá").
- Papi-chulo: hombre con buena apariencia física y que utiliza esta para aprovecharse de las mujeres.
- Papi-chulo: hombre que complace a una mujer sexualmente a cambio de obtener beneficios de ella.
- Papi-chulo: hombre jóven de familia con buena condición económica que lo mantiene financieramente= "Niño mimado".

Answer (score 0):

Eso se debe haber popularizado con el reggaeton aquí en Perú no era muy conocido pero se extendió  a raíz de la música , se hizo una [moda](http://catalogo-total.blogspot.com/2013/12/guia-de-moda-zapatos-de-primavera.html) y tendencia . ya que actualmente se utiliza para describir tanto hombre como mujer atractiva físicamente . pero la mayor parte de las personas se lo dicen de una manera de decir atractivo pero de alguna manera divertida

Comment: Se usa Papichulo para mujer?

Answer (score 0):

En Brasil, *papichulo* (así, sin espacio) es utilizado en jerga para describir a un papá lindo y atractivo.

Comment: mmm.....¿Brasil?   ¿Español?

Answer (score 0):

La palabra "papichulo" es un neologismo tomado del diminutivo de "papá" y de la palabra: "chulo".

*Chulo* tiene varias acepciones de como entenderla de acuerdo al ambiente cultural donde se pronuncia y como se pronuncia y donde se utiliza. Por ejemplo, en un ambiente cultural propio del inframundo a bajo pueblo.

La palabra "papichulo" expuesta como ofensa se refiere a un proxeneta de porte elegante que vive de la "prostituta", "servidora sexual" o "terapeuta sexual", en un ambiente del medio y alto pueblo, o suprapueblo: la palabra "papichulo", expuesta se refiere a un halago que utiliza para ensalzar a un hombre hermoso y elegante, atractivo. De ahí la utilización del diminutivo "papi" para referirse a su complejo de Electra con respecto al padre o "papá" y de lo atractivo refiriéndose a él como hombre con el cual puede tener amor-sexual, que no es incestuoso.

Comment: Ojala lo editaras con la escritura correcta de mayúsculas y minúsculas. Es terrible leer un texto así.

Comment: Absolutamente de acuerdo con @DGaleano - para hacer inteligible un texto es imprescindible que entre por los ojos. Lo puse en minúsculas y separé en párrafos. Aún así, sería bueno que lo revisaras porque hay frases sintácticamente incoherentes. Eso sí, ¡buena respuesta dentro de lo que cabe!

Comment: @fedorqui you are a trooper!!!